# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

I am writing a function that takes a textbox object from the tkinter library as an argument. When I fill in the textbox and hit the button, I get

```
"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'."
```

I know for a fact the textbox object has get() as a function. I even imported the tkinter library into the file that has my function. Here's a simplified version of what I am trying to do in two files:

main:

```
import tkinter
import save_file
app = tkinter.Tk()
textbox = tkinter.Text(app).pack()
button = tkinter.Button(app, command=lambda: save_file.save_file(textbox))
```

save_file:

```
import tkinter
def save_file(textbox):
    text = textbox.get()
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure that's the closest dup for this question, but you can find plenty of others in the Linked and Related lists from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pack()` returns `None`; you want to store *just* the `Text()` object, then call `pack()` on it separately:

```
textbox = texinter.Text(app)
textbox.pack()
```

Comment: Yep that's all it took. Awesome! Thanks! To clarify though, the problem was that my choice of syntax was actually assigning the value returned by pack() to my variable?

Comment: Exactly; you chained the calls and the return value of `texinter.Text()` was used to look up the `pack` method, and the expression ends up producing what that last method call produces, not the intermediary results.

Answer (score 0):

`tkinter.Text(app).pack()` returns None  so you set  `textbox` equal   to None

Change to:

```
 textbox = tkinter.Text(app)
 textbox.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the .pack() method on a tkinter Text object returns None.

The fix:

```
import tkinter
import save_file
app = tkinter.Tk()
textbox = tkinter.Text(app)
textbox.pack()
button = tkinter.Button(app, command=lambda: save_file.save_file(textbox))
```